# How do I set the links in the Array in my vuejs project as img src links

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I am trying to add the links to the source part of img by pulling the links from an array with links, but the photos are not coming even though I apply the code below. I'm not getting any errors either. Can anyone find the error or suggest a different way?

```
 <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" class="d-flex child-flex" >
<v-card class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" v-for="link in productImages" :key="link.id">  
 <v-img :src="link" class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></v-img>
 </v-card>
</v-col>
```

It works when I don't use v-for, I couldn't understand why.

```
    <v-card class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
<v-img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></v-img>
</v-card>
```

data:

```
  productImages: ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg"],
```

Comment: do you have images with these `["example.com", "test.com","test2.com"]` names?

Comment: @RotikenGisa no i just wrote them for example. normally there are image links in their place. When I click on the link, the image opens.

Comment: Great. Are you using absolute or relative paths? Maybe you can provide a sample link then I'll be in a better position to help you.

Comment: @RotikenGisa I've added an sample link.

Comment: I can see that the link is working correctly, and thus should render the image. Have you tried using a string e.g. src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" without the dynamic values?

Comment: @RotikenGisa ` <v-card class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" v-for="link in productImages" :key="link.url">  
                      <v-img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></v-img>
        </v-card>`  it is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241489/discussion-between-rotiken-gisa-and-cagrihan-gunay).